# App Center iOS build unable to verify integrity

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, apple-developer

I'm working on a **Xamarin** application and I'm doing **iOS** builds to run and test on different devices using **App Center**.

Everything was ok, on Apple Developer I created the Ad-Hoc certificate, the provisioning file, and the identifier and it was all good.

During the last implementation, I added on **Entitlements** the **Associated Domain** due to enabling the possibility to use the App Link and let the user open the application using a link provided via email.

I updated the *Identifier* adding the feature also to it and I downloaded it and uploaded it again to the dedicated branch on App Center, but now when I try to download the app to the device I receive this message:

> Unable To Install "App Name". This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.

I tried different ways trying to solve it:

- Create a completely new certificate with a new identifier, provisioning, and .p12 file
- Checked Entitlement feature list correspond to the identifier list on Apple Developer
- Used different versions of SDK and Xcode on App Center

I already searched around on the web but they talk about the provisioning file list but I already checked and it is updated.

Thank you for your help and for your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you get to solve this issue?

Comment: 2023 and i'm facing this as well, no idea what else I could try besides recreating profiles.